# How to implement modal inside another modal in angular-strap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-strap

I'm using angular-strp for modal box. My requirement is i want to show the information about the page when page loads in the modal box. When user click ok on the modal box I need to close that modal and show user another modal to choose country.

i'm using ng-click on the first modal ok button to call a function to close the first modal and open another modal in that function.

Is there anyway to chain modal from opening one by closing another in angular-strap?